# Mocking of an (redux store) object to test js function in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

Im new to frontend testing in general and i have a CartScreen in react with a `calculateTotalQuantity` function which im trying to test with jest. Since hours i try to change the value of `cartItems` (create a new `cartItems` in testclass and asign some dummy qty data). I tried out mocking, spies but without success. I simply cant change the value of `cartItems`. My attempt is to put in some valuable data and expect the correct output of `calculateTotalQuantity` function.

This is how my `CartScreen`.js looks like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../actions/cartActions";


function CartScreen(props){

    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);

    const {cartItems} = cart;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    const productId = props.match.params.id;
    const qty = props.location.search ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const removeFromCartHandler = (productId) => {
        dispatch(removeFromCart(productId));
    }
 

    function calculateTotalQuantity() {

        
        let totalQty = cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + parseInt(c.qty), 0);
        console.log("QUantity");
        console.log(totalQty); 
        
        return totalQty
    }
```

My `testclass` looks like this:

```
import { JsonWebTokenError } from "jsonwebtoken";
import CartScreen from "./CartScreen";

it("calculates total quantity",() => {
    const cartItems = [
        {
          id: 1,
          "qty": "3",          
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            "qty": "4",
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            "qty": "6",
        },
    ];

    const mockFn = jest.fn(CartScreen);
    mockFn();
    mockFn.cartItems = cartItems;
    console.log("Mockfunktion: ")
    console.log(mockFn());
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockFn).toEquals(13)
  
    
})
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're attempting here. You appear to mock your component, call your component with no properties, call it again, and expect the return value of your component to be `13`. There's a lot going on here--it might make more sense to take a step back and spin through some React testing tutorials first.

Comment: Yeah im sorry its little confusing all. 

I want to test the `calculateTotalQuantity` function of `CartScreen.js`. For this purpose, i try to mock the value of `cartItems` with the `cartItem` Object of my testclass. So in my main class i would have the new value of `cartItems`, process them with `cartItems.reduce` to calculate the `totalQty`. With my test Object, the value should be equal to 13.
I hope this is better to understand now... :)

Comment: Personally I'd remove the method from the class and just pass in the cart items. Barring that, you can pass the cart items to the component and check for a correct tender. You don't want to mock the class you're testing--that's the class you *wanr* to be real.